# Where is the .Xauthority for GDM on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: ubuntu, gdm, xauth

According to the [Ubuntu manpage for gdm](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man8/gdm3.8.html)

```
XAUTHORITY
           Upon session startup, GDM sets the XAUTHORITY environment variable to a session-
           specific file in /run/gdm3.
```

, but I don't see anything in this directory, except an empty file called "greeter".

Ubuntu has just restarted and the GDM login screen is displayed.

Where is the .Xauthority file?;)